# Adobe RMSDK in iPhone

Tags: iphone, adobe

I am researching on Abode's RMSDK for iOS. I ve the SDK with all the library files. There is a sample project given in that SDK which works fine. But If I include the lib file in my own sample app its is throwing a linker error. Can any one help me out in this. Is there any sample code that i can refer regarding this SDK.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get the SDK from adobe but I can't found the example ? can you help me for that example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add reference to a rmservice project insteed of using lib file. 
Then, you must verify all paths described in project settings is correct. I've had to placed my project in same folder of rmservice so that I don't have to change any setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use it as a lib, you should perform two actions:

1) Add the lib in the build phases, on the Link Binary with libraries area. Be sure to select your target on the left side, not the project.

2) In your build settings on the Library Search Paths you should write down the path where the library resides.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, if you are doing RMSDK11, then follow the book2png in samples folder, this will allow you build you own application.
If you are doing RMSDK10, then you probably will run into 32/64 bit support problem.